# velocity at the peak point of the curve

Tags: derivatives, slope

Why is it so that in the velocity time graph, even though the derivative of the function at a point x is zero, the velocity is said to be maximum:
[image]

Comment: I guess the horizontal axis is time and vertical one is the space. But what is x, is it time or space?

Comment: Who says "the velocity is maximum" there? As you suspect, the velocity is $0$. The height is a maximum. The velocity might be at a maximum when the second derivative is $0$.

Comment: At the maximum, the vehicle returns. To do so it must invert its speed, i.e. let it pass through zero.

Comment: @Ilis, yes, the horizontal axis represents time and the vertical represents the function of time as velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we take the function $v(t)=s'(t)$ describing the velocity, then $v'(t)=s''(t)$ describes the acceleration and $v'(t)=0$ means (of course if $\exists \delta>0 \forall \epsilon<\delta\,: v'(t-\epsilon)\cdot v'(t+\epsilon)\leq 0$), that the velocity reaches the local extremum (maximum or minimum).

On the other hand, If we have a function $s(t)$ describing dependence of distance and time, then $s'(t)$ describes the velocity. $s'(t) =0$ means then, that the velocity is equal to $0$, not maximum. This is for the distance time graph.

Comment: did some error above, and tried to fix it